# FileZilla times out when transferring large file

Tags: filezilla

I have a file residing on a FTP site that I am trying to download.  The FTP site is a secure site and requires a user name and password.  The size of the file I am trying to download is 2.98GB.  Part way through the transfer I get the error message:

```
Connection timed out 
File transfer failed after transferring 501,407,504 bytes in 693 seconds
```

I have tried it a few times and it seems to timeout at different spots.  If I click through the folder structure it seems to keep it from timing out.  Is there anything I can do to stop it from timing out when downloading larger files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as my experience goes, the FileZilla can be configured to timeout the connection if inactive for xx seconds:

> If no data is sent or received during an operation for longer than the specified time, the connection will be closed and FileZilla will try to reconnect.

[image]

**Usually a timeout during a large file transfer** is due to server configurations where the user account is allowed to have an active login for a certain amount of time. If that time gets expired (*common on very large files*), the server kills the connection.

Aldo, fileZilla should re-establish the connection and resume the file transfer.

---

Check with your system administrator for that issue.